# Session tracking mode to url in servlet 2.5

Tags: java, jersey-1.0

how can i get xml like this in jersey

```html
<items>
<item><name>cow</name></item>
<item><name>cat</name></item>
</items>
```

i have class with name "item" and a class with name "items"
in class item i have field with name "name" and in class "items"
i have a list of "item"
there is my code

```
@XmlRootElement
public  class Item {
@XmlElement(name = "item" , required = true)
private String item;
 public String getItem() {
 return item;
}
}

@XmlRootElement
public  class Items{
@XmlElement(name = "items" , required = true)
List<Item> items;
 public List<Item> getItems(){
 return  items;
}
}
```

in this code there is error and bug :(
i do not know how get list of objects from xml

i am new please help

Comment: i asked this question from another computer header of question is anything else sorry

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the error message?

Comment: tank you Lutz it work if i send xml like <items><items><item></item></items></items> there is two items tag at first